# Excel 2010 from different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

So sheet 1 is currently empty and on sheet 2 i have the following:

`Column A`     `Column B`     `Column C`   `Column D`

`Hobbies`      `travelling`   `swimming`   `Jogging`

What do i have to do so that if i write `Hobbies` in Column A of Sheet 1, Columns B, C and D of Sheet 1 are filled in automatically with the contents of Columns B,C and D of Sheet 2?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. This may sound trivial, but I just want to clarify your question; you are asking for sheet1 to reflect what you put in the columns of sheet2? Or are you wanting the data on sheet2 to be the first sheet of the workbook?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Put this formula in cells B1, C1, D1 of Sheet1, then copy down as far as needed

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet2!$A:$D,COLUMN(),0),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

=if(a1 = "Hobbies", b1:d1 = Sheet2!b1:Sheet2!d1,"")

What we are saying is cell a1 (column a, row 1) = Hobbies then cells b1 through d1 = the cells b1 through d1 of Sheet2 otherwise leave it blank.